# Origin of using the phrase "folks" to refer to parents

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Why can the phrase "your folks" be used to refer to "your parents"? What is the origin of this usage?

Comment: My husband always uses folks when he's referring to his parents.I have always used parents. We both grew up in Maine - he in a small city, I - in a small town, both in the same County. His mother grew up on a farm in a rural area, different County, in Maine. She always said folks, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary's earliest citation for *folks* meaning ‘the people of one's family, parents, children, relatives’ is dated 1715. It’s an example of semantic narrowing in which a word used to describe a general category takes on a specific meaning.

Comment: Like Germanic _Tier_ ('animal') being narrowed to _deer_ in Modern English.

Comment: And *people*, with the same meaning, is even older: the OED has a (probable) citation from 1474